# Can't compile "check.c" file

Tags: compiling

I'm trying to install [Magick Rotation](https://launchpad.net/magick-rotation). Within the steps there's a C file that I have to compile but it gives me errors.

The command I'm using is `gcc check.c` and here's the output:

```
/tmp/ccDA1vH4.o: In function `main':
check.c:(.text+0x2a): undefined reference to `XOpenDisplay'
check.c:(.text+0x89): undefined reference to `XRRSelectInput'
check.c:(.text+0xa2): undefined reference to `XNextEvent'
check.c:(.text+0xbb): undefined reference to `XRRGetScreenInfo'
check.c:(.text+0xdb): undefined reference to `XRRConfigRotations'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

...any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be very trivial. I just forgot to `-o checkmagick64 -lX11 -lXrandr` *(didn't read whole instructions)* so the correct command is

```
gcc check.c -o checkmagick64 -lX11 -lXrandr
```

Answer (score 0):

On first glance it looks like a missing library (libx11-dev). If the library is indeed installed then the order of the compiler call might be wrong (the -lX11 switch needs to come last).